# Blackberry share application

Tags: blackberry, app-store, ota

How to make support for both App World and the application being embedded?
What is the difference between OTA and App World?

If I will build applications for the web and will put a link to the Internet (eg via apache) 
It will be OTA ?

How much is the official service OTA or App World?

Please give references for which I can read this issue.

Answer (score 1):

OTA means "Over The Air". There are several ways of getting the app code installed on a BB device. One way is via USB cable + BB DesktopManager app, for instance. When you are talking about OTA and App World as if they are different things - this is not correct. The fact is to get an app from the App World you'll have to use OTA implicitly (you'll start the BB browser, it will make a remote request to RIM server, etc. - this means OTA is used).

I believe there is no difference on how AppWorld and your custom server would do this.

RIM provides a video tutorial on this:
[BlackBerry® Smartphone Over The Air Download By User](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/BlackBerry-Smartphone-Over-The-Air-Download-By-User/ta-p/447533)